# How to fetch the Android versionCode & versionName from a .apk file outside the android environment?

Tags: android-manifest

The use case is this.  I write custom applications for corporations.  These applications are proprietary and for a variety reasons are inappropriate for the Android Market.  Some customers require that the applications automatically contact a corporate server on a regular basis to check for updates and, if needed, automatically download and install them.  I have a working mechanisms for doing this, but it is not as robust as I would like.  The best solution would be for the application running on the device, to pass its Android versionCode (and perhaps VersionName) to the server where these would be compared with the versionCode of the potential upgrade .apk on the server.  Only if the .apk on the server represents an upgrade would it be uploaded to the device and installed.

There are many suggested solutions posted.  One common one is to place a separate text file on the server which contains the versionCode and versionName, but it is possible through administrative error for this text file to get out of sync with the values in the .apk file.  The result would be constant and unnecesary downloads.  The various other solutions, such as using apktool or any of its wrappers, while workable, have other drawbacks.

There are workarounds which I am pursuing, but all seem to involve persisting some additional information about an .apk file (e.g. a checksum) that was recently downloaded and installed.  This information can be passed to the server and compared.  This can be made to work, it is just not as clean ss I would like.

I am looking for a library .jar file that will allow the versionCode and versionName to be fetched from the .apk file.  Basically is would be passed the File object representing the .apk file location and provide methods to get the versionCode and versionName.

An other suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, but is not for the faint of heart.  I downloaded [AXMLPrinter2.jar](http://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar&can=2&q=) which is a self contained .jar file that can be used to read, interpret and dislay the contents of an android .XML file.  In particular, it does a nice job of displaying the contents of an AndroidManifest.xml in human readable format.  However, I needed to get programmatic access to the contents of the AndroidManifest.xml.

This is where it gets interesting.

I first extracted the MANIFEST.XML file in AXMLPrinter2.jar to find the main class, which is AXMLPrinter.

I then de-compiled the AXMLPrinter.class, which turns out to be a relatively simple wrapper around an AXML parser contained in AXMLPrinter2.jar, and derived a new class called ReadAndroidManifest.  As this class is inteneded for use on a server, it has a simple constructor ReadAndroidManifest(File apkFile) and provides two methods:  getVersionCode() and getVersionName().

I simply added the AXMLPrinter2.jar file to my web-app library (unmodifed!) and included the derived class, ReadAndroidManifest, in the part of the servlet that determines if an apk file represents an upgrade.

Obviously, this technique can be extended in a more general way to provide access to all elements of the AndroidManifest.xml file, but the simple version above works perfectly for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of working out for the same thing and after reading through so much posts, I came into a workaround which I think it is the most comfortable way of geting packageName and version from APK through pure JAVA code (out of Android environment).

First, I have donwloaded [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool-install-windows-r05-ibot.tar.bz2&can=2&q=). In case the link is not working for some reason, it is apktool, with the name of **apktool dependencies and helper script for windows** under the download page. Then, I unzip the folder and get its aapt.exe, place into my java project folder.

Then, inside my Java code, I just write in this way:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("PATH_TO_APKTOOL_AAPT.exe", "dump", "badging", "path_to_your_apk_file");
 Process p;
 String output = "";
 try {
p = builder.start();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
    line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
    output += line;
    }
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("package: name='(.*?)'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(output);            
        m.find();
    System.out.println("package name:" + m.group(1).trim());
    pattern = Pattern.compile("package:.*?versionCode='(.*?)'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    m = pattern.matcher(output);
    m.find();
    System.out.println("version:" + m.group(1).trim());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`

Well, it is kind of less side-effect and simple way of obtaining APK package name and version code :)